# Creating two instances but output remains same

Tags: objective-c

I am new in Objective C and I am trying to run one of the examples from the book but the result of two instances gives the same result. Here is the code:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//--- @interface section ---
@interface Fraction: NSObject
-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int)d;
@end

//--- @implementation section ---
@implementation Fraction

int numerator;
int denominator;


-(void) print
{
   NSLog(@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator); 
}

-(void) setNumerator: (int) n
{
   numerator = n;   
}

-(void) setDenominator: (int) d
{
   denominator = d; 
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * fzrpool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

 Fraction *myFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    [myFraction setNumerator: 1];
    [myFraction setDenominator: 5];

    Fraction *fzr = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    [fzr setNumerator: 3];
    [fzr setDenominator: 2];

    NSLog (@"The value of myFraction is: ");
    [myFraction print];
    NSLog (@"The value of fzr is: ");
    [fzr print];

    [fzrpool drain];
return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2013-12-17 11:56:01.187 helloworld[1988] The value of myFraction is:
2013-12-17 11:56:01.187 helloworld[1988] 3/2
2013-12-17 11:56:01.187 helloworld[1988] The value of fzr is:
2013-12-17 11:56:01.187 helloworld[1988] 3/2
```

I can not use @autoreleasepool{} here because I am working on windows, gcc. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your both numerator and denominator are global, hence the last value will persist. You want both of them to behave like an ivar/property, so need to put them inside { and }

Comment: those `{` and `}` returns error. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//--- @interface section ---
@interface Fraction: NSObject
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}
-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int)d;
@end

//--- @implementation section ---
@implementation Fraction

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}

-(void) setNumerator: (int) n
{
    numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator: (int) d
{
    denominator = d;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    Fraction *myFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    [myFraction setNumerator: 1];
    [myFraction setDenominator: 5];

    Fraction *fzr = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    [fzr setNumerator: 3];
    [fzr setDenominator: 2];

    NSLog (@"The value of myFraction is: ");
    [myFraction print];
    NSLog (@"The value of fzr is: ");
    [fzr print];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those braces at implementation returns the following error:
`15:1: error: inconsistent instance variable specification
In function '-[Fraction print]':
19:20: error: 'numerator' undeclared (first use in this function)
19:20: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for e
ach function it appears in
19:31: error: 'denominator' undeclared (first use in this function)

 In function '-[Fraction setNumerator:]':
24:4: error: 'numerator' undeclared (first use in this function)
In function '-[Fraction setDenominator:]':
29:4: error: 'denominator' undeclared (first use in this function)
`

Comment: It worked for me. I think u r using the older version of Xcode. Never mind i have edited the code.

Comment: @iCoder that worked great, but I am still confuse. I can't use book's example because I am using older version?

Comment: YES. I strongly suggest u get books that are released recently as they will contains the updated information. Or u can refer http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials . There are lot of tutorials. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your both numerator and denominator are global, hence the last value will persist. You want both of them to behave like an ivar/property, so need to put them inside { and }

```
@implementation Fraction
{
int numerator;
int denominator;
}
```

As you are in Windows with GCC,

move the above  blocks with both `ints` and  to `@interface` then you can compile.